# How to improve development speed for Ionic 4 app?

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have developed Ionic 4 app which have more 50+ screen(includes screens, components, popups etc). 
It takes more time to build & run or even live reload even for small ui change.
Is there any way to improve development faster?

My Environment Setting:

```
Ionic:
   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.4.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.6
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.0
Cordova:
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, ios 4.5.5
System:
   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.2
   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v10.13.0
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

To run app on android device(ie Nexus 5 (Android V 6.0.1)) it takes around 72 seconds to run in device and live reloading takes 70 seconds.
I have used many plugins (ie required for app), so can't run app in browser (ie ionic serve).
Running app in simulator also not much help, since it consume much more memory that make it slow.

Any suggestion is appreciated?
Thank You.

Comment: Hey how did it go? Did you try Med's answer? I am going to try it too soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to upgrade your project to Ionic 5 and Angular 9. Angular 9 brings the new Ivy renderer which one and only purpose is better tree shaking and faster incrementally build performance capabilities. Ivy will only (live) update the instructions you have changed compared to the Angular 8 and below build process which also updated all parent elements and components.

In theory you should gain dramatic build performance improvements for live updates.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but currently can't update app, since its large app. & it will take too much time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large application so you can modifie the preloadStrategie and for me i have imporve my application speed with this strategie see this link and let me khnow :

https://ionicframework.com/blog/how-to-lazy-load-in-ionic-angular/

Comment: Thank you, will try it.